# npm is not installing on ubuntu

Tags: package-management, npm

I  can't install npm.Whenever i try to type

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

this comes
 `E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?' what should i do

Answer (score 0):

Something is using your 'apt-get'/'apt'. Run these commands and you should be good to go:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```